# How to implement code coverage for angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular5, code-coverage

Please provide the steps for code coverage report for angular 5?

[image]

Comment: Angular in basic set up(``ng new``) provide set of plugins to generate code coverage. In your case it seems that you don't have any tests(which is not true probably) or your path to match files with tests is wrong. Can you provide **tsconfig.spec.json** and **test.ts** files?

Answer (score 1):

It works in Angular 6 under Linux, in Angular 5 it should looks like the same.

`npm run ng test -- --code-coverage`

Comment: Yes, it does work in angular 6 but it has a different set up in angular 5. 

Can anyone help me?